# Query criteria for matching 3 of 6 fields

Tags: kotlin, criteria, corda

I would like to select rows in the Corda (M14) database with a criteria that matches at least 3 of 6 fields and sort these results by matching fields.

Here is the SQL syntax to select fields:

```
WHERE (field1 = ?) + (field2 = ?) + (... = ?) > 3
```

and to order it:

```
ORDER BY ((field1 = ?) + (field2 = ?) + (... = ?)) DESC
```

Another way of doing it :

```
SELECT *, ((field1 = @inputFirst) + (field2 = @inputLast)) as Matches
FROM mytable
HAVING Matches > 1
ORDER BY Matches DESC
```

I started to create the criteria:

```
vaultCriteria
            .or(QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(field1))
            .or(QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(field12))
            .or(QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(field3))
```

But I am stuck now on how to GROUP theses results by fields' matching number and SORT these, any ideas ?

Thank you,

Loup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For M14 release you have 2 options:

1) Get a jdbcSession directly from the DatabaseTransactionManager:

```
val jdbcSession1 = DatabaseTransactionManager.current().connection
```

2) Get a jdbcSession indirectly from a RequeryConfiguration object:

```
val jdbcSession2 = RequeryConfiguration(<dataSourceProperties>).jdbcSession()
```

where `<dataSourceProperties>` looks something like this:

```
private fun makePersistentDataSourceProperties(): Properties {
    val props = Properties()
    props.setProperty("dataSourceClassName", "org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource")
    props.setProperty("dataSource.url", "jdbc:h2:~/test/vault_query_persistence;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE")
    props.setProperty("dataSource.user", "sa")
    props.setProperty("dataSource.password", "")
    return props
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For advanced custom SQL queries it is recommended you use a standard `JDBCSession`, obtainable from the `ServiceHub`.

Please see https://docs.corda.net/head/api-persistence.html?highlight=jdbcsession

Comment: Thank you, but `jdbcSession` is not included in M14, the (latest) version our Cordapp is based...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested how far it's possible to take the API, but I've had success (on current Master) by writing custom SQL - e.g.

```
        val session = services.jdbcSession()
        val consensusQuery = """
        SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT(NULLIF(factObject, ?)), COUNT(*)
        FROM submission_states
        WHERE factSubject = ? AND factPredicate = ?
        """
        val consensusStatement = session.prepareStatement(consensusQuery)

        consensusStatement.setString(1, factConsensusQuery.factObject)
        consensusStatement.setString(2, factConsensusQuery.factSubject)
        consensusStatement.setString(3, factConsensusQuery.factPredicate)

        log.info("SQL to execute: " + consensusStatement.toString())
        val rs = consensusStatement.executeQuery()
```